# Visual Studio - Change "Treat warnings as errors" to all for every new project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings, csproj

Whenever I create a new .net project in Visual Studio, I want the "Treat warnings as error" build option to be set to "All" by default. I now have to manually change it after creating every project, but it's easy to forget.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about new projects in a solution or clean new project/solutions?

Comment: Adding a new project to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a powershell script to add it to all projects:

https://david.gardiner.net.au/2011/05/turn-on-as-errors-for-all-projects-in.html

You could make that run as part of a pre-push git hook.